Is a real line an elementary set?
Now I'm studying Measure party from Rudin's PMA.
It says that, if a set $A$ can be written as a union of finite number of intervals, then $A$ is an elementary set.
(Now, I will denote the colletion of elementary sets as ${E}$.)
Then I think $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty, \infty)$ itself is a single interval, then $\mathbb{R}\in E$. Is this right?
Then if we generalize this a little bit more, then in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself an elementary set? Since $\mathbb{R}^n = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{R}=(\mathbb{R},0,\cdots,0) \cup (0, \mathbb{R}, \cdots, 0) \cup \cdots \cup (0,\cdots,0,\mathbb{R})$?

$\Bbb R$ is an interval of $\Bbb R$, although I can't really speak for the definitions in Rudin's book. For $n\ge2$, $\prod_{i=1}^n\Bbb R\ne\bigcup_{j=1}^n \left({0}^{j-1}\times\Bbb R\times {0}^{n-j}\right)$; specifically $(1,1,\cdots,1)\in\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\Bbb R\right)\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^n \left({0}^{j-1}\times\Bbb R\times {0}^{n-j}\right)$.

Oh yes you're right.
Anyway, can I consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an elementary set?
